# JavaScript: How to override base class function?

Tags: javascript, telerik

I'm new in JavaScript.

I have base Telerik's JavaScript class:

```
Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.prototype =
{
    _contextmenu: function(e) {...}
}
```

I derived my class from Telerik's base class:

```
Parus.Controls.ParusGrid.prototype =
{
}

Parus.Controls.ParusGrid.registerClass("Parus.Controls.ParusGrid", Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid);
```

How can I override _contextmenu function in my class and allow execution of base _contextmenu function?

Comment: What does registerClass method do?

Comment: The registerClass designated my class Parus.Controls.ParusGrid was derived from Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get class derived from Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid you should set prototype to derived class.

```
Parus.Controls.ParusGrid.prototype = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid();
```

then override your method as you want

```
Parus.Controls.ParusGrid.prototype._contextmenu = function(e) {
    //base method
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.prototype._contextmenu.call(this,e)        
}
```